# Как доработать вставку фото через ctrl v

Tags: php, javascript

```js
var images = [];

document.body.querySelectorAll("#text")[0].addEventListener("input",render,false);
function render(){
 var div = document.body.querySelectorAll("#preview")[0];
  var text = document.body.querySelectorAll("#text")[0].value;
  images.map(function(el){
   var img = "<img width='100px' src='"+el.data+"' />";
   text = text.replace(el.textCode,img);
    
  });
  div.innerHTML = text;
}
document.body.querySelectorAll("#text")[0].addEventListener("paste",function(event){
  var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  for (index in items) {
    var item = items[index];
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      var blob = item.getAsFile();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event){
       images.push(new myimg(event.target.result));
    document.body.querySelectorAll("#text")[0].value += images[images.length-1].textCode;
      render();
      }; // data url!
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }
});

function myimg(data){
 this.data = data;
  this.textCode = "{image"+images.length+"}";
}
```

```html
<textarea  id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Надо добавить в него автоматическую загрузку на сервер, и скрывать текстовый идентификатор картинки в поле

Comment: Собсна в чем проблема-то? Где вам нужно подсказать? Или за вас написать? Круто вы кодите: там нашел, тут попросил чтоб допили как надо и т.д.)))

Comment: Если вам все таки нужно помочь, то в голову пока приходит такой вариант: `reader.onload = function(event){` - этот ивен вызывается после загрузки изображения, собсна в нем и нужно вызывать ajax, а для передачи можно использовать `fileReader.readAsDataURL` - он должен вернуть представление в вашей картинки в `base64` а на сервере вы его декодируете.

Comment: Собственно подсказать как скрыть (только визуально) текстовую инфу фотки, обработчки сделал))